# Improve CustomScrollView behavior

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-sliver

[Behavior i want to achieve](https://youtube.com/shorts/XUNiWueGEP4?feature=share)

[Closest behavior i get](https://youtube.com/shorts/U8YZ_Q0v6cU?feature=share)

I tried using `SliverPersistentHeader` and `SliverList` inside `CustomScrollView` and achieved almost same behavior except one thing. `SliverList` is using background and not rounding it's coners. I need `CustomScrollView` to make one scrollable area to scroll `SliverList` from any part of screen.

Here is my code:

```
const double _kFlexibleFromHeight = 0.2;
const _kMainVerticalPadding = 20.0;
const _kMainHorizontalPadding = 15.0;

class SliverBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SliverBottomSheet> createState() => _SliverBottomSheetState();
}

class _SliverBottomSheetState extends State<SliverBottomSheet> {
  late final ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            AppColors.mainBluePurple,
            AppColors.bgLightOrange,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0.2, 0.43],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _HeaderDelegate(
                  controller: _controller,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                      _kFlexibleFromHeight),
            ),
            //just wrapper to add Decoration to SliverList
            SliverGroupBuilder(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(50))),
              child: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (ctx, index) => ListTile(
                            title: Text('tile $index'),
                          ),
                      childCount: 40)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final double height;

  _HeaderDelegate({
    required this.controller,
    required this.height,
  });

  double get topPadding => min(
        _kMainVerticalPadding * 2,
        max(
          0,
          _kMainVerticalPadding -
              (controller.hasClients ? controller.offset / 10 : 0),
        ),
      );

  double get bottomPadding => min(
        _kMainVerticalPadding * 2,
        max(
          0,
          _kMainVerticalPadding +
              (controller.hasClients ? controller.offset / 10 : 0),
        ),
      );

  double _getOpacity(BuildContext context) {
    double result = 1;
    if (!controller.hasClients) return result;
    result = 1 -
        (controller.offset /
            ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2) / 100) /
            100);
    if (result < 0) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (result > 1) {
      result = 1;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    double shrinkOffset,
    bool overlapsContent,
  ) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: shrinkOffset,
          bottom: controller.offset > 0 ? 0 - shrinkOffset : null,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: _getOpacity(context),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: height,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: topPadding,
                  bottom: bottomPadding,
                ),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: List.generate(
                    5,
                    (index) => Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Text('Child $index'),
                        )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      true;
}
```